# Spring Cloud Config Server using properties from server in actual application

Tags: spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

I use Spring cloud config server embedded in an application. Can I populate that application's placeholders?

If my config server gets a property `${some.property} from git, vault, native;` can I actually use that `${some.property}`, in the sever's actual application?